# javascript dom, how to handle "special properties" as versus attributes?

Tags: javascript, dom, code-generation

issue is whether to use property or attribute.

have not found this documented, so have run some tests (chromium 12):

**property <=> attribute**

```
accept, alt, formMethod, formTarget, id, name, placeholder, type, maxlength, size
form: method, name, target, action, enctype
```

- can set either property or attribute
- will reflect to property or attribute
- exception 1: if form property will first look for element of that name (!)
- exception 2: action property rewrites itself using value, passes set value to attribute
- exception 3: enctype maintains its integrity, but passes set value to attribute

**property <= attribute**

```
value, autofocus, checked, disabled, formNoValidate, multiple, required
```

- setting property has no effect on attribute
- setting attribute also sets property

**property => attribute**

```
indeterminate
```

- setting property also sets attribute
- setting attribute has no effect on property

**propetry >< attribute**

```
defaultValue, validity, defaultChecked, readOnly
form: novalidate
```

- setting property or attribute has no effect on the other

---

to me this seems pretty random behavior.

given a random attribute/value to apply to an element, here are the best rules I have come up with (modified as per Tim Down (thanks!) below):

- if class, write with `classList`, read with `className` property
- if a form, always *read* using attribute (and be a little careful)
- if `typeof element[propName] != "undefined"`, use property, ie, `element[attr]=val`
- otherwise, use attribute, ie, `element.setAttribute(attr,val)`

is this even close to being right?

note: interestingly, if you have a form with an element named "novalidate", is it even possible to access the `novalidate` property of the form itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Except for rare special cases listed below, always use the property. Once the browser has parsed the intial HTML, attributes are no help to you unless you're serializing the DOM back to HTML for some reason.

Reasons to always favour properties:

- dealing with properties is simpler (see Boolean properties such as `checked`: just use `true` and `false` and never worry whether you should be removing the attribute, or setting it to `""` or `"checked"`)
- not every property maps to an attribute of the same name. For example, the `checked` property of a checkbox or radio button does not correspond to any attribute; the `checked` attribute corresponds to the `defaultChecked` property and does not change when the user interacts with the element (except in old IE; see next point). Likewise `value` and `defaultValue`.
- `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` are [broken in older versions of IE](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute).

Special cases:

- Attributes of `<form>` elements. Since each form input is mapped to a property of its parent `<form>` element corresponding to its `name`, it's safer to use `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` to obtain properties of the form such as `action`, `name` and `method`.
- Custom attributes, e.g. `<p myspecialinfo="cabbage">`. These will not generally create equivalent properties on the DOM element object, so `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` should be used.

One final consideration is that there is not an exact correspondence between attribute and property names. For example, the property equivalent of the `class` attribute is `className`, and the property for the `for` attribute is `htmlFor`.

Comment: think we're saying the same except for two things: 1) `name`, which would be wrong in a form if there exists an element with a name of "name", and 2) given a random attr/value pair, if the attr is not a property, then will be treated as an attribute.  because the app is spec'd only against higher end browsers have no need to support older versions of IE (to date, afaik, even newer versions).

Comment: `name` is a fair point, and is a special case for form elements. It's a shame form inputs are mapped to properties of the `<form>` element for that very reason (what would have been wrong with just providing `form.elements`?), but it's too late to change that now. Re point 2, are you talking about custom attributes (e.g. `<p myspecialattr="cheese">`? In which case I'd have to agree with that, since `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` are the only ways to access those. Btw, there's no guarantee `hasOwnProperty()` will work on host objects such as DOM nodes, so I'd use a different test.

Comment: wow - you're good!  one, I will test form properties to see how well the sync with attributes.  two, if not `hasOwnProperty()`, what would you use?

Comment: `typeof`, usually. `typeof element[propName] != "undefined"` will work. You're probably ok to use `hasOwnProperty()` in the browsers you're targeting but `typeof` is safer because host objects are obliged to respond to `typeof` but not obliged to inherit from `Object.prototype`, which is where `hasOwnProperty()` is defined.

Comment: finished work on form properties - see updated comparisons.  exception 2 is actually pretty cool.  anyway, a little tricky there.