# JavaScript Element.value vs Element.getAttribute("value")

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

I've started learning JavaScript recently but there's something that I'm confused with :

**what is the different between** `Element.value` **and** `Element.getAttribute("value")` **?**

actually my problem is , when I try to copy the value of an `input` element with type of `text` to another one , if I use the first method (`Element.value`) It works fine but if I go with the second method It copies the first value given to the element and It never gets updated when I change the text inside the `textbox` , this behavior seems odd to me ! can you guys please explain what's going on here ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello JavaScript</title>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    <input id="Text2" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript file :

```
var myButton;

window.onload = function () {

    myButton = document.getElementById("Button1");
    myButton.onclick = function () {
        var val = document.getElementById("Text1").getAttribute("value");  
        //var val = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
        document.getElementById("Text2").setAttribute("value", val);
    };

};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that `element.value` is real time and if a user changes let's say, a textbox input, it will reflect that, and show you the new value.

While `getAttribute('value')` will still show the original `value="whateverWasHere"` value.

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9Mat/)

Comment: For more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973678/difference-between-element-value-and-element-getattributevalue

Answer (score 2):

The `value` attribute's value is what you set when you write the HTML.

This **attribute**'s value, when read, is used to fill the element's `value` **property**.

That **property** is what you get afterwards when you use `Element.value` and that's what changed by the user or most JavaScript functions. The **attribute** isn't changed when the user changes the value through the interface.

In short, you almost always want to use `Element.value` and almost never `Element.getAttribute("value")`.