# Why is the `value` attribute empty whereas the `value` property has the correct value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-input

I have an `input` field that will cache its `value` attribute. Example:

```
$("#signUpEmail").keyup(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value); // Works
  console.log($(this).attr("value")); // Doesn’t work
});
```

If I log them both in the console, `e.target.value` will return my `input` field, but not `$(this).attr("value")`. Can anyone explain why that is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Element.value and Element.getAttribute("value")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973678/difference-between-element-value-and-element-getattributevalue)

Comment: then use `$("#signUpEmail").keyup(function(){ var value = $(this).val();  alert(value); })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can explain why is that so?

`e.target.value` accesses the *DOM property*, which always represents the current value of the input field.

On the other hand, `$(this).attr("value")` accesses the *HTML attribute*, which is the value of the input as specified in the HTML markup. It doesn't update when the value is changed by the user.

You could use `$(this).prop('value')` to access the property via jQuery, but as already mentioned, [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is the usual way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).attr("value"); //can access only default value
```

For example,

```
<input type="text" id="signUpEmail" value="email"/>
$(this).attr("value"); //returns email
```

Instead use **`prop()`**

```
 $(this).prop("value"); //for getting dynamic values
```

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="signUpEmail" />
$(this).prop("value"); //returns whatever you press
$(this).attr("value"); //returns undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching the value *attribute*, which represents the *default* value not the *current* value.

Use the `val()` method instead of `attr()`.

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery to get text of input field use:

```
$(this).val();
```

and for labels:

```
$(this).text();
```