# PHPUnit Selenium2 Error on getting current input text value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'm having strange behavior while trying to get input text value:

```
$this->byXPath( "//input[contains(@id, '_rule_1_display_times')]" )->value();
```

Error output:

> PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException : GET
>   /session/3ef42f7e-f5f5-459d-92e2-6377c6f05e61/element/4/value Build
>   info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26
>   23:59:50' System info: host: 'vytautas', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name:
>   'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-49-generic',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_75' Driver info: driver.version: unknown

It's strange cause I can set value to this input without any problem:

```
$this->byXPath( "//input[contains(@id, '_rule_1_display_times')]" )->value(8);
```

Any ideas what's wrong with getting current input text value?

Comment: I found out that it works via attribute method: 
$this->byXPath( "//input[contains(@id, '_rule_1_display_times')]" )->attribute('value'). But still the question persists what is wrong with ->value()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value gives you the current value of the field vs attribute(value) that gives you the original value.
It was asked here: [Difference between Element.value and Element.getAttribute("value")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973678/difference-between-element-value-and-element-getattributevalue)
So I'm guessing your current value is simply empty/not set.