# Date Input Wont Console Log Value

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to see what value my date input field has however I am always left with null in my console.

I am using the following JS to `console.log` my date input value:

```
document.getElementById('date_of_birth').addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

Here is my input field also:

```
<input id="date_of_birth" 
class="input input--bravo pad-1/2 span-1x field-date_of_birth is-invalid" 
data-palm="span-1x" 
placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" 
pattern="\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}*"
name="payload[date_of_birth]" 
type="date" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
```

When I select a date my JS triggers however prints null into the console. Why doesn't it show the date I have selected? I only want to see the date so I can see how the value is formatted so I can setup some validation for it.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Element.value and Element.getAttribute("value")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973678/difference-between-element-value-and-element-getattributevalue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

`getAttribute` may used for defined or custom properties. You should use `.value`

```js
document.getElementById('date_of_birth').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="date_of_birth" 
       class="input input--bravo pad-1/2 span-1x field-date_of_birth is-invalid" 
       data-palm="span-1x" 
       placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" 
       pattern="\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}*" 
       name="payload[date_of_birth]" 
       type="date" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
```

you can use `getAttribute` in this below case.

```js
document.getElementById('date_of_birth').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

```html
<input id="date_of_birth" 
       class="input input--bravo pad-1/2 span-1x field-date_of_birth is-invalid" 
       data-palm="span-1x" 
       placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" 
       pattern="\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}*" 
       name="payload[date_of_birth]" 
       value="01/01/2016"
       type="date" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `console.log(this.value);` instead of `console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));`

`this.getAttribute` will catch the HTML atrribute

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('date_of_birth').addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log($('#date_of_birth').getDate());
});
```

You can use above Code to get Date of that HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try:

```
document.getElementById('date_of_birth').addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('date_of_birth').addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('date_of_birth').value);
});
```