# Getting element value in javascript returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, null, attributes

When I use `.getAttribute()` instead of `.value`. It assigns null to the local variable `value` instead of the string.

```
for(let el of document.querySelectorAll("input,select"))
{
    // this works
    let value = el.value;

    if(el.classList.contains("foo") == true)
    {
        // this returns null
        value = el.getAttribute("value");
    }

    settings[el.name] = value;
}
```

Any ideas why `.getAttribute()` is returning null instead of the value?

This is inside a vue component, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973678/difference-between-element-value-and-element-getattributevalue) post .

Comment: It's not recommended to manipulate the DOM in this way using vue since it's a data-driven framework

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim its getting the values, not setting them and its necessary since the select element is generated on load using a jQuery color picker plugin so it can't be bound.

Comment: I think @Swati is correct [Difference between Element.value and Element.getAttribute("value")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973678/difference-between-element-value-and-element-getattributevalue)