# Reasons for getAttribute returning Null

Tags: javascript, setattribute, getattribute

I have a large program with a form where information fills and updates based on other information.  It worked one-day, the next my field value returns null. There are no error messages.  I was looking for a generic list of "things to check."

Among other things, the form takes in 2 numbers, multiplies them, and returns the Sum. The variable for quantity is always returning NULL.

```js
function calcprod(form, elem, val, theID) {
  var theForm = document.forms[form];
  var price = theForm['proforma_prod_lines_price_unit'].getAttribute('value');
  var quantity = theForm['proforma_prod_lines_num_unit'].getAttribute('value');
  prodTotal = Math.round((price * quantity) * 100) / 100;
  console.log(price + " x " + quantity + " = " + prodTotal);
  theForm[concat('proforma_prod_lines_total')].setAttribute('value', prodTotal);
}
```

```html
<form name="status" id="status" action="?tab=proforma" method="post"  >
<input type="text" name="proforma_prod_lines_num_unit" id="proforma_prod_lines_num_unit" value="" onkeyup="calcprod('proforma_status_update', this.id, this.value,'')" />
<input name="proforma_prod_lines_price_unit" type="text" id='proforma_prod_lines_price_unit' value="" onkeyup="calcprod('proforma_status_update', this.id, this.value,'')" />
<input name="proforma_prod_lines_total" type="text" value="" readonly />
</form>
```

Comment: If you want the value that the user entered into the form, use `.value`, not `.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: Your javascript code is referencing a form, however there is no form in your example.

Comment: Does it really return `null` or does it return an empty string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973678/difference-between-element-value-and-element-getattributevalue

Comment: Changing ('value') to .value didn't work, but changing the entire line to document.getElementById("proforma_prod_lines_num_unit").value; did work.  Can someone explain why or provide a link?  It worked for a few months using the ('value').

Comment: Thank you, the answer is easy to find when you know the question.