# list of live, property-only element attributes?

Tags: html, dom, properties

[Some sites](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute) erroneously indicate that IE will only return the value of certain element attributes if the property form is used (e.g. `element.className` instead of `element.getAttribute("class")`); [as of IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347148.aspx) this [no longer seems to be necessary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429.aspx).

However, [other sites](http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties#value) point out that the current value of some attributes in the DOM (e.g. `input.value` and `input.checked`) may indicate the original document value and not reflect its current object property value.

If I'm wanting to synchronize the current state of a HTML document with some arbitrary DOM tree, is there a list of properties that must be accessed in `element[propertyName]` form rather than their `element.getAttribute(attributeName)` form in order to get and set the current value?

Comment: This is why we use frameworks like jQuery that handle all this ugliness internally so we don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Diodeus: I'm afraid I'm not able to use jQuery in my situation. The question remains.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006253/javascript-dom-how-to-handle-special-properties-as-versus-attributes

Comment: That is helpful---thanks. I also found http://stackoverflow.com/a/707702/421049 . And HTML5 will be adding new properties no doubt---as well as bringing more inter-browser incompatibilities. :(