# getAttribute() versus Element object properties?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Expressions like `Element.getAttribute("id")` and `Element.id` return the same thing.

Which one should be used when we need attributes of an HTMLElement object?

Is there any cross browser issue with these methods like `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`?

Or any impact on performance between directly accessing object properties vs using these attribute methods?

Comment: Similar question: [Properties and Attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`getAttribute` retrieves the *attribute* of a DOM element, while `el.id` retrieves the *property* of this DOM element. They are not the same.

Most of the time, DOM properties are synchronized with attributes.

However, the synchronization *does not guarantee the same value*. A classic example is between `el.href` and `el.getAttribute('href')` for an anchor element.

For example:

```
<a href="/" id="hey"></a>
<script>
var a = document.getElementById('hey')
a.getAttribute('href') // "/"
a.href // Full URL except for IE that keeps '/'
</script>
```

This behavior happens because according to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#adef-href), the href property must be a well-formed link. Most browsers respect this standard (guess who doesn't?).

There is another case for the `input`'s `checked` property. The DOM property returns `true` or `false` while the attribute returns the string `"checked"` or an empty string.

And then, there are some properties that are synchronized *one-way only*. The best example is the `value` property of an `input` element. Changing its value through the DOM property will not change the attribute (edit: check the first comment for more precision).

Because of these reasons, I'd suggest you keep using the DOM *properties*, and not the attributes, as their behavior differs between the browsers.

In reality, there are only two cases where you need to use the attributes:

1. A custom HTML attribute, because it is not synced to a DOM property.
2. To access a built-in HTML attribute, which is not synced from the property, and you are sure you need the attribute (for example, the original `value` of an `input` element).

If you want a more detailed explaination, I strongly suggest you read [this page](http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties). It will take you a few minutes only, but you will be delighted by the information (which I summed up here).

Comment: +1 for generally good advice. The synchronization thing is slighty off though: the `value` property of an input does get its initial value from the attribute but is otherwise not tied to it at all. The `value` attribute is fully synchronized instead with the `defaultValue` property. Likewise `checked` and `defaultChecked`. Except in old IE (<=7 and compatibility modes later), which has broken `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`.

Comment: Added your comment as "further explaination" :-)

Comment: If you're trying to figure out if a value is non-default, you're better off using attributes.  Many modern browsers will return a default value (e.g. `input.formAction`) or empty string (e.g. `a.download`), which makes things ambiguous.  The only exception are values that aren't 2-way synced, such as `value`.

Comment: If id is not set at all in the dom, getAttribute will return null and element.id will return an empty string. Is this a standard?

Comment: Another case where you might want to use getAttribute is with <form> elements.  If you have a <form> with a child element that has id="id" or name="id" then formelem.id is the child element, not the id of the form element.

Answer (score 14):

`getAttribute('attribute')` normally returns the attribute value as a string, exactly as defined in the HTML source of the page.

However, `element.attribute` could return a normalized or calculated value of the attribute. Examples:

- `<a href="/foo"></a>`

  - a.href will contain *full* URL
- `<input type="checkbox" checked>`

  - input.checked will be true (boolean)
- `<input type="checkbox" checked="bleh">`

  - input.checked will be true (boolean)
- `<img src='http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff'>`

  - img.width will be 0 (number) *before the image is loaded*
  - img.width will be 64 (number) when image (or first few bytes of it) is loaded
- `<img src='http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff' width="50%">`

  - img.width will be the *calculated* 50%
- `<img src='http://dummyimage.com/32x32/000/fff' style='width: 50px'>`

  - img.width will be 50 (number)
- `<div style='background: lime;'></div>`

  - div.style will be an object

Answer (score 3):

`.id` saves the function call overhead. (which is very small, but you asked. )

Comment: Hi gdoron, just for the sake of curiosity: I tried to find an 'official' explanation of this (beyond the empirical test, which is clear enough ;) ) but with no success. Do you have any link about it?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/el-getattribute-id-vs-el-id) `getAttribute` is more slow than `id` property.

**PS**

Oddly enough both statements perform very bad on IE8 (compared to other browsers).

Answer (score 3):

Always use the properties unless you have a specific reason not to.

- `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` are broken in older IE (and compatibility mode in later versions)
- properties are more convenient (in particular, those corresponding to boolean attributes)

There are [some exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590937/96100):

- accessing attributes of `<form>` elements
- accessing custom attributes (although I'd discourage using custom attributes at all)

I've written about this subject a few times on SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7010268/96100
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4456805/96100

Comment: Before IE 8, properties and attributes [were treated identically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347148(v=VS.85).aspx). As you alluded to earlier, properties are the way to go.

Comment: @MattMcDonald: Yes, that's the brokenness to which I was alluding. I didn't expand on it in this answer because I felt I'd done so enough in other answers I linked to :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below example to understand this completely. For the below DIV

`<div class="myclass"></div>`

The `Element.getAttribute('class')` will return `myclass` but you have to use `Element.className` which retrieves it from the DOM property.

Answer (score 0):

One area where this makes a big difference is with css styling based on attributes.

Consider the following:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

divs[1].custom = true;
divs[2].setAttribute('custom', true);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

div[custom] {
  background: #36a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>A normal div</div>
<div>A div with a custom property set directly.</div>
<div>A div with a custom attribute set with `setAttribute`</div>
```

The div with the custom property set directly doesn't reflect the value to the attribute, and is not selected by our attribute selector (`div[custom]`) in the css.

The div with the custom attribute set using `setAttribute`, however, is able to be selected using a css attribute selector, and styled accordingly.