# How to get an element's ID from event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider a piece of code that looks like the following:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){

});
```

I know there is a way to get the element type from `e.target`, i.e. `e.target.nodeName`, but how can I get the id of that element from that? If that can't be done, is there another way to get the id of the element that was clicked on?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `e.target.id`. e.target represents `DOM` object and you can access all its property and methods.

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);    
});
```

You can convert the DOM object to jQuery object using jQuery function `jQuery(e.target)` or `$(e.target)` to call the jQuery functions on it.

Answer (score 21):

To get the attribute of a target element in JavaScript you would simply use:

```
e.target.getAttribute('id');
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280487/5025060 for the subtle distinction between DOM properties and their attributes.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Note that the OP was asking about `e.target`, which isn't necessarily the same as `this` - especially not if the click handler is bound to the body.

Comment: True, although my aim was to find a way to get the id of an element from within an event; e.target was just a suggestion.

Comment: Well if `this` is the right element just say `this.id`, you don't need to create a jQuery object and call the `.attr()` function.

Comment: @nnnnnn, wow. Working with jQuery absolutly forgot about native js. `this.id` is much easier to use, of course

Comment: `this` doesn't seem to work for me; `$(this).attr('id');` returns `undefined` and `this.id` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I suspect the problem is as per my original comment: 'this' is the body element because that's what the click handler was attached to, and the body doesn't have an id specified...

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 $('body').on('click', '*', function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function (e) {//you can do $(document) instead $(body)
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('id'));//<--this will find you the each id of `<a>`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selectıonImg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.getAttribute('rock')) {
    userChoıceImg.innerHTML=<img src="./img/taş.png" alt="rock">
  }  
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.