# How to access a custom HTML attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
<span id="roleDropName" class="dropdown_btn_val" dropopt="1">Thamaraiselvam</span>
```

this is my code i need to get `dropopt` using above id or class and i did following code it shows nothing to me

```
console.log(document.getElementById("roleDropName").dropopt);
```

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+get+custom+attribute+value

Comment: @FelixKling: Why didn't you close this question as a duplicate? There are plenty that ask the exact same question.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I wasn't able to find a good (i.e. canonical) one...

Comment: Woot!, my google-fu is stronger than yours :P Fair enough, though :P

Comment: @Cerbrus: :D yeah, mine is letting me down. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the jquery version. First you need to get the id name, and then you can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function which is to get the attribute value or even added the new one.

```
console.log($('#roleDropName').attr('dropopt'));
```

Comment: OP removed the tag in the meantime btw.

Comment: Apparently it wasn't the OP but an other editor. Added back the tag.

Answer (score 6):

None of the DOM elements has a property `dropopt`, so you get back the value `undefined`.

If you want to access **custom attributes**, you have to use [**`getAttribute`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
document.getElementById("roleDropName").getAttribute('dropopt');
```

However, custom attributes are better defined as [**`data-*` attributes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). Then you can also use [**`dataset`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) in browsers that support it.

---

Related questions:

- [Custom attributes - Yea or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yea-or-nay)
- [getAttribute() versus Element object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10280250/218196)