# HTML Input element (field.validate) is always undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm having two text boxes defined with an `onblur` event. On pressing tab, whenever the `onblur` event is get called `field.validate` is always `undefined`.

At the same time, when I'm trying to print `field.name` or `field.getAttribute("validate")` it does return the proper value.

```
<input width="100%" type="text" name="NV_active" id="NV_active" value="5"  onblur="return doValidate(this);" validate=" return validateValueField(document.getElementById('NV_active'), 'Active' );">

<input width="100%" type="text" name="NV_throttled" id="NV_throttled" value="15"  onblur="return doValidate(this);" validate=" return validateValueField(document.getElementById('NV_throttled'), 'Throttled' );">

function doValidate(field) {
    console.log("field.validate- " + field.validate); //always printing undefined
    console.log("getAttr- " + field.getAttribute("validate")); //return validateValueField(document.getElementById('NV_active'), 'Active' );
    if (field.validate != null) {
        var f = new Function(field.validate);
        return f();
    }
    return true;
}

function validateValueField(field, displayName)
{
  if ((field.name == 'NV_activePollingInterval') || (field.name == 'NV_throttledPollingInterval') )
    {
        //some validation code and error alert message
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure it out why it's always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Using `field.getAttribute('attr')` you retrieve the *value* of the DOM element's attribute.

Using `field.attr` you retrieve the *property* `attr` of the DOM element and they are not always the same thing.

I recommend you to check this SO question: [getAttribute() versus Element object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10280250/855738) and the accepted answer, it should help you.