# angular2 getting value of custom attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have input elements with a custom attribute call field.

```
<input type="text" (change)="recordChange(currentField,row)" #currentField field="caution">
```

On the change event, the currentField came back like this one the console.

```
 <input type="hidden" field="caution" value="plus icon red">
```

I was able to do currentField.value to obtain the value, but I can't seems to figure out how to get the field value.  What am I missing?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `getAttribute(...)` method for that on elements:

```
currentField.getAttribute('field')
```

See also [getAttribute() versus Element object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280250/getattribute-versus-element-object-properties)

Comment: Feel kind of stupid right now, thanks for your help.