# How to target the event that you click and use for offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-attributes

I have several *div* elements. On the *mousedown* event I am getting the elements attribute that I clicked on and then using Jquery offset method,
I can't seem to trigger the `$(elt)` properly, so that it picks up as Jquery.

I am trying to use as least as possible of Jquery library as wan to get rid of it.

*offsetLeft* and *offsetTop* are both JavaScript properties that are defined on an HTML element. *offset()* is a jQuery method that requires a jQuery object. 
I understood that all you need to is wrap the element like so `$(elt)`.

I get error on the last line on JS before closing tag.

```
 elementBlock.on('mousedown',function(e){
        var el = e.target.nodeName;
        var elt = e.target.getAttribute('id');
        console.log(elt); // i get the clean attribute
        console.log(el); // i get DIV
        elt.tmp.left = e.clientX - $(elt).offset().left;

}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div  id="elementBlock">
                  <div id="blue-left"></div>
                  <div id="blue-right"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `$(elt)` syntax but only if you prepend *elt* with the ID selector (i.e. `#`). Refer to the jQuery documentation for [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for more information.

Also, `elt` is assigned to the *id* attribute, which is a string. The [string prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) has no property *tmp*. To set the style *left* you could access the *style* attribute of the element:

```
e.target.style.left = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
```

#### Edit:

You mentioned you are "*trying to use as least as possible of Jquery library*". We can remove all jQuery functions and use native Javascript, as in the example below. It uses event delegation with [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (Note that there are limitations with support by older browsers, such as Internet Explorer- see the [notes about adding event handlers with IE in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)), checks to see if the element clicked on is within the element with *id* attribute *elementBlock* (i.e. the element itself or a child element), and then utilizes the properties you mentioned: [HTMLElement.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and [HTMLElement.offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) instead of jQuery's [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/).

And you likely noticed that usage of `e.target.getAttribute('id')`, was replaced by `e.target.id` - the property of the DOM element is sufficient. For more of an explanation on this, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280250/getattribute-versus-element-object-properties#answer-10280487).

```js
//observe DOM ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //observe clicks on the DOM
  document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    //look up the DOM tree from the event target to see if we clicked within the elementBlock container
    var target = clickEvent.target;
    while (target && target.id !== 'elementBlock' && target !== undefined) {
      target = target.parentNode;
    }
    //if we clicked within the elementBlock container
    if (target && target.id == 'elementBlock') {
      //log out the offsetTop and offsetLeft
      console.log('offsetTop: ', clickEvent.target.offsetTop);
      console.log('offsetLeft: ', clickEvent.target.offsetLeft);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="elementBlock">elementBlock
    <div id="blue-left">L</div>
    <div id="blue-right">R</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answear but  elementBlock.tmp.top is mean to be elements temporal left. I am storing the data on the right in the left column :)
also instead of the two lines that you did for let elt and element, can i just join them so I have a sorted code: like   var elt = $(e.target.getAttribute('id'));

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs you've got two good answers now, did one or both answer your question? You should upvote and/or accept them, or ask for further clarification. Has your question been answered?

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs unless you update your post to give us more information, we can't know about the data in the right and left column, or that *.tmp* might be a property you set... Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `$(e.target)` instead of `$(elt)`

The problem in your current code is that if you want to target a jQuery element by ID you need to prefix that selector with a `#`.

So `$("#" + elt)` would also work, but they suggestion above is cleaner. See here for more information about jQuery Selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/