# HTML DOM datetime-local value not passed

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I've got a table which displays datetime like this:

```
<td id="start-1" value ="2017-03-15T00:00">2017-03-20 20:00:00</td>
```

When user wants to edit row, a `modal window` will be opened with filled data. But the value of time is not passed to `modal window` (datetime-local is shown blank).
However if the string "2017-03-15T00:00" is passed directly to inside script as below:

```
 document.getElementById("start-e").value = "2017-03-15T00:00";
```

, it does show it, but the code below does not work:

```
 document.getElementById("start-e").value  = document.getElementById("start-1").value;
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] your question is very unclear

Comment: @upicik if modal window load a new page so  you have to use the ref of this new page to call js there.

Comment: There is no value on a td. It is a custom attribute and you need getAttribute to get it

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280250/getattribute-versus-element-object-properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - Form fields have `value` attributes, TDs not:

```
document.getElementById("start-e").value  = document.getElementById("start-1").getAttribute('value');
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the code as below:

```
document.getElementById("start-e").value = document.getElementById("start-1").innerHTML;
```

as `td` is not a control, it is an html tag. You have to use `.innerHTML` to get its child content.

Answer (score 2):

Generally DOM elements in javascript have no `value` property. I guess the `start-e` is an input, which does have and that's why you can use `document.getElementById("start-e").value`
(see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

Otherwise you need to use the attributes, like @santho suggested.
His answer will work:`document.getElementById("start-e").value  = document.getElementById("start-1").getAttribute('value');`