# What is the difference between .getAttribute("name") and .name?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes, cross-browser

I have a simple web-application with an input text field in it looking like this:

```
<input id="txtip" type="text" value="10.1.1.50" />
```

The address `10.1.1.50` is a default value for an ip address. And from javascript I would read it like this:

```
txtip.getAttribute("value")
```

Now let's suppose to change it to `10.1.1.49`. In google chrome the above javascript code will still return `10.1.1.50`, while the expression

```
txtip.value
```

returns `10.1.1.49`.

What is the difference? What is the "right way"?

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: `value` is an attribute of `input` so that's why you can access it via `getAttribute` but `value` is also a property of node type `input`. I would use `txttip.value`

Answer (score 3):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('testBox');

$(document).focusout(function () { 
alert('el.value = ' + el.value);
    alert('el.getAttribute("value") = ' + el.getAttribute('value'));
    e.preventDefault();


});
```

```html
<h2>Change value in the text box</h2>


<input id="testBox" type="text" value="original value" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Found this on web might help you try following code type something and focusout

The difference is that element.value is real time and if a user changes let's say, a textbox input, it will reflect that, and show you the new value.

While getAttribute('value') will still show the original value="whateverWasHere" value.

Comment: Not always, it's a mixed bag. See [*getAttribute() versus Element object properties?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280250/getattribute-versus-element-object-properties) The use of jQuery in your answer is unnecessary and detracts from what you're actually trying to show.

Comment: Thanks for the comment !

Comment: thank you guys, now its clear