# Can't extract next page link using xpath within puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, xpath, puppeteer

I'm trying to figure out a way to scrape next page link from a [webpage](https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings) using xpath within puppeteer. When I execute the script, I can see that the script gets gibberish result even when the xpath is correct. How can I fix it?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const base = "https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com";
let url = "https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings";

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    page.waitForSelector(".company-listing");
    const nextPageLink = await page.$x("//a[@aria-label='Next'][./span[@aria-hidden='true'][contains(.,'Next')]]", item => item.getAttribute("href"));
    url = base.concat(nextPageLink);
    console.log("========================>",url)
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Current output:

```
https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.comJSHandle@node
```

Expected output:

```
https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings?page=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's a missing `await` on `page.waitForSelector(".company-listing");`. Not awaiting this defeats the point of the call entirely, but it could be that it incidentally works since the very strict `waitUntil: "networkidle2"` covers the selector you're interested in anyway, or the xpath is statically present (I didn't bother to check).

Generally speaking, if you're using `waitForSelector` right after a `page.goto`, `waitUntil: "networkidle2"` only slows you down. Only keep it if there's some content you need on the page other than the `waitForSelector` target, otherwise you're waiting for irrelevant requests that are pulling down images, scripts and data potentially unrelated to your primary target. If it's a slow-loading page, then increasing the timeout on your `waitFor...` is the typical next step.

Another note is that it's sort of odd to `waitForSelector` on some CSS target, then try to select an xpath immediately afterwards. It seems more precise to [`waitForXPath`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options), then call `$x` on the exact same xpath pattern twice.

Next, let's look at the docs for [`page.$x`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagexexpression):

> #### `page.$x(expression)`
>
> expression `<string>` Expression to evaluate.
>
> returns: `<Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>>`
>
> The method evaluates the XPath expression relative to the page document as its context node. If there are no such elements, the method resolves to an empty array.
>
> Shortcut for `page.mainFrame().$x(expression)`

So, unlike `evaluate`, `$eval` and `$$eval`, `$x` takes 1 parameter and resolves to an elementHandle array. Your second parameter callback doesn't get you the href like you think -- this only works on eval-family functions.

In addition to consulting the docs, you can also `console.log` the returned value to confirm the behavior. The `JSHandle@node` you're seeing in the URL isn't gibberish, it's the stringified form of the JSHandle object and provides information you can cross-check against the docs.

The solution is to grab the first elementHandle from the array returned by the function and then `evaluate` on that handle using your original callback:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const url = "https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url);
  const xp = `//a[@aria-label='Next']
    [./span[@aria-hidden='true'][contains(.,'Next')]]`;
  await page.waitForXPath(xp);
  const [nextPageLink] = await page.$x(xp);
  const href = await nextPageLink.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("href"));
  console.log(href); // => /company-listings?page=2
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

As an aside, there's also `el => el.href` for grabbing the href attribute. `.href` includes the base URL here, so you won't need to concatenate. In general, [behavior differs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280487/6243352) beyond delivering the absolute vs relative path, so it's good to know about both options.

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. However, I could not execute the exact script you suggested as it threw some error pointing at the dot ***.catch***. Thanks.

Comment: Strange -- which Node version are you using and what did the error say, out of curiosity?

Comment: This was because of a typo ***browser?.close()*** in the last line of your code. However, it did work when I kicked out that ***?*** sign. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that's [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). I recommend upgrading Node to 14 or higher.