# JavaScript - Using QuerySelector on multi-nested lists

Tags: javascript

If I have a nested list like this:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#number-one">Number 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#number-two">Number 2</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#number-three">Number 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#number-four">Number 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#number-five">Number 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to be able to get the href values from every one of these links using querySelector.

Something like this only returns the links in the top level :

```
const getNav = document.querySelector('.nav li');
```

How can I get all of the href values from every link in a nested list?

Comment: I think it should get them all. If not, I'll delete this comment. Just make sure you use `document.querySelectorAll()` if you want to select multiple elements

Comment: Something like `[...document.querySelectorAll('.nav li>a')].map(dom => dom.href);` ?

Answer (score 1):

In one line with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) & [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  :

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.nav li a')].map(({href})=>href)
```

Gives *result*:

```
['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943233/javas…ng-queryselector-on-multi-nested-lists#number-one', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943233/javas…ng-queryselector-on-multi-nested-lists#number-two', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943233/javas…-queryselector-on-multi-nested-lists#number-three', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943233/javas…g-queryselector-on-multi-nested-lists#number-four', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943233/javas…g-queryselector-on-multi-nested-lists#number-five']
```

### live example

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('.nav li a')].map(({href})=>href))
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#number-one">Number 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#number-two">Number 2</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#number-three">Number 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#number-four">Number 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#number-five">Number 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Might as well add a live example

Comment: Added see update!

Comment: Great answer, could still improve it by mentioning the difference between `.href` and `.getAttribute("href")`

Comment: Glad to help, Yes there's a difference and already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280250/getattribute-versus-element-object-properties)

Comment: I know, I meant you should include that in your answer

Answer (score 0):

querySelector only returns one element, in this case you will get the first li element after the nav class.
To get all li you can use:
querySelectorAll - as it return an array matching your select options.
[MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

To get an attribute you'll use: element.getAttribute('href')

[MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/element/getAttribute)

Example:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav li a')
elements.forEach(el => { 
 // logic goes here 
 let href = el.getAttribute('href')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get every `href` values.

```
const getNav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav li a');
   
    getNav.forEach(element=>{
        console.log(element.getAttribute("href"))
    })
```

`querySelectorAll` gets all of the `a` elements that are in `.nav li` then by a foreach loop you'll be able to get all href values of them.