# Get Properties in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a button.
As soon as i click the button i get an event object.
with the event object i can say event.target.

With event.target i get following string:

```
<button class="mdi mdi-barley mdi-input-icon" id="vegan" date="7"></button>
```

i get the id with event.target.id

i get the class with event.target.class

if i say event.target.date i get null

i set the date attribute with the method element.setattribute();

How can i get thevalue of the prop date?

Comment: So you *set* the attribute with `setAttribute` but you're not sure what you *get* the attribute with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript dom, how to handle "special properties" as versus attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006253/javascript-dom-how-to-handle-special-properties-as-versus-attributes)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `date` is a reserved property. You can access it here by using `getAttribute` instead:

```js
console.dir(document.querySelector('button').getAttribute('date'));
```

```html
<button class="mdi mdi-barley mdi-input-icon" id="vegan" date="7"></button>
```

But it would be more appropriate to use a data attribute instead of using a non-standard attribute:

```js
console.dir(document.querySelector('button').dataset.date);
```

```html
<button class="mdi mdi-barley mdi-input-icon" id="vegan" data-date="7"></button>
```